# Can Tesseract be used for Sinhala handwritten text recognition?

Tags: tesseract

I wish to restore damaged Sinhala handwritten documents. Please let me know: Can Tesseract be used for Sinhala language also?

Comment: StackOverflow questions should generally be more substantial than something that could be researched using Google. Here are some articles that might help you: https://medium.com/@isurianuradha96/training-sinhala-language-with-tesseract-4-1-version-3cd96ce84b6a https://www.researchgate.net/publication/331287878_Sinhala_Character_Recognition_using_Tesseract_OCR.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout the [`tessdata` folder the from tesseract-ocr GitHub](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) repository:

- There's `sin.traineddata` for the actual Sinhala **language**, and
- there's `script/Sinhala.traineddata` for the Sinhala **script**.

Copy one of them (or both) to your `tessdata` folder, maybe located at `C:\tesseract\tessdata` on some Windows machine.

For example, running Tesseract from the command line, you can then use

```
tesseract myimage.png output -l sin
```

or

```
tesseract myimage.png output -l Sinhala
```

I took a screenshot of the [Sinhala script Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhala_script), and cropped the following part:

[image: Crop]

Both above commands result in the following output:

```
සිංහල අක්ෂර මාලාව
```

That seems fine to me, but I don't claim to be able to read or understand any Sinhala script or language!

So, in general: Yes, it seems, you can OCR Sinhala texts!

**BUT:** As for any script, and maybe even more difficult for non-Latin scripts, you probably won't get good results on handwritten texts. OCR on those texts is some field of research on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for Node.js:

```
const T = require("tesseract.js");
T.recognize("./imagepath", "sin", { logger: (e) => console.log(e) }).then(
    (out) => console.log(out.data.text)
);
```

To import Tesseract use this:

```
npm i tesseract.js --save
```